# Python CNN Implementation: logits and labels must have the same shape ((4, 2) vs (4, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have been working on building a CNN with multiple inputs for a binary classification problem in Python using the Keras module. It appears that I have built all of the input layers and hidden layers correctly, with a ValueError occurring after the first epoch saying that the dimension of my logits/labels are not the same shape (see title). The code for my output layer is:

```
num_classes = 2

### code for other layers ###

# fully connected layers for output
fc1 = Dense(128,activation='relu')(flatten)
fc2 = Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax')(fc1)

# complete the model
model = Model(inputs=[m1.input,m2.input,m3.input,m4.input],outputs=fc2)
```

After this step, I go on to compile the model and begin to fit it with my data and the training/validation labels. This is where the error occurs, and I am not sure what to do. Similar questions have suggested reshaping the labels with

```
train_labels = train_labels.reshape(-1,1)
val_labels = val_labels.reshape(-1,1)
```

but this resulted in the same error. Any thoughts would be welcome on how I could fix this.

Comment: Did you try to one hot encode your labels?

Comment: @Frightera it is a binary classification problem so this shouldn't be an issue (already 0's and 1's), but I will try that to see

Comment: You are using softmax with 2 labels so you need to one hot encode them unless you use 1 neuron with sigmoid activation.

Comment: Yes, Did you tried as suggested above?